# My JSF webapp on Tomcat goes to localhost

Tags: jsf, tomcat, localhost

My JSF webapp on Tomcat that resides in http://www.deprem.gov.tr:8080/pro1/bir.jsf goes
 directly to localhost and nothing is found.

What might be the possible causes?

Answer (score 0):

Several possible causes:

- You've hardcoded a `localhost:8080` redirect somewhere in your webapp. Maybe in some filter?
- The host `www.deprem.gov.tr` is by your DNS server resolved to `localhost`.
- The host `www.deprem.gov.tr` is in your `etc/hosts` file resolved to `localhost`.

This is not necessarily related to JSF or Tomcat. It's just a misconfiguration :)

Comment: Thank you BalusC I checked the code I didn't see any hard code like localhost:8080. What I didn't understand is that on second trial of "http://www.deprem.gov.tr:8080/pro1/bir.jsf" (paying attention this address rather than localhost:8080 ) , it ran.

Answer (score 0):

As @BalusC says, it is a configuration issue. I suggest you search for "www.deprem.gov.tr" in your project files if it is not in hosts file. You will probably see it somewhere hardcoded.

Comment: Thank you fmucar I checked the code I didn't see any hard code like localhost:8080. What I didn't understand is that on second trial of "http://www.deprem.gov.tr:8080/pro1/bir.jsf" (paying attention this address rather than localhost:8080 ) , it ran.